# USART1 Interrupt IRQHandler how to receive string

Tags: c, stm32, interrupt-handling, iar, usart

I am able to receive bytes of incoming data via serial from the pc to STM32051 board but any time that i type in 2 or more characters to send at a time the interrupt stops until i reset the board to repeat same process... How can i change the IRQHandler code to receive payload of 23 bytes or string? can anyone help me with a sample code or modify my current code so i can receive this payload? thanks,

Here's the IRQHandler function that can receive only one byte.

```
void USART1_IRQHandler(void)
{
  unsigned char getbuffer [200], finalbuffer, targetdata[];
  if(USART_GetITStatus(USART1, USART_IT_RXNE) )
  {
    getbuffer [i] = USART_ReceiveData(USART1);
    buffer = (getbuffer [i]); 
    USART_SendData(USART1, buffer);//Feedback 
    i++;          
  }
}
```

Comment: You mess with StdPeriph API. You can't use `USART_ReceiveData` and `USART_SendData` within interrupt handler. UART data receiving is not trivial operation. There are amount of examples in Internet. Also read source of StdPeriph: developers wrote whole instrucion in commnts how to use this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir , i have solve the problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32679035/receiving-number-as-string-uart

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the `RXNE` interrupt bit in the interrupt handler for the USART.

```
if(USART_GetITStatus(USART1, USART_IT_RXNE) )
{
  __HAL_USART_CLEAR_IT(USART1, USART_IT_RXNE);
…
}
```

Please remove `USART_SendData(USART1, buffer);` as this is a blocking function which takes the same time to transmit data as it takes to receive data. As such it won't work. Please create a transmit in your main loop which transmits the buffer when something was received.

Also `USART_ReceiveData` isn't HAL standard so I'm assuming but: it just needs to read the `RDR` register and not wait for incomming data as you are using interrupts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir , i have solve the problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32679035/receiving-number-as-string-uart